# WAMP is redirecting php requests without extension

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have a problem with my local WAMP server on Windows, it automatically adds the extension ".php" to the url if the file exists. For example, in the following structure:

```
+ www
  + files
    - main.php
```

if I call the url `http://localhost/files/main` it automatically shows me the file `main.php`.

I was trying to identify where the redirection is but I have not found it. I clarify that **I do not have any ".htaccess" file**, I have even tried disabling the extension `mod_rewrite`, I have also searched for a `VirtualHost` that is redirecting and I have not found anything either.

Removing the Type `application / x-httpd-php .php` no longer redirects, but of course, it no longer interprets the PHP files.

I need to solve this since it is giving me problems when wanting to rewrite a url with "htaccess" since it adds the extension ".php" to the file.

For example, with the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) files/main.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And the following `main.php` file:

```
<?php print_r($_GET); ?>
```

When calling the url `http://localhost/files/main/param` the file `main.php` runs and shows me the url: `files/main.php/param` (note that the extension has been added ".php" to the main file).

Does anyone know what may be due and how to fix it?

Comment: If I call the url `http://localhost/files/main/` (With slash at the end) it executes the file `main.php` and shows the url `files/main.php/`

Comment: I'm a little late to this party (thread closed), so I have to comment here for future readers. The problem is MultiViews is enabled. Just add Options -MultiViews to your .htaccess to disable it and the extensionless urls will stop redirecting

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the mod_rewrite and create a virtual host. Follow this tutorial to do it: 
https://artisansweb.net/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite/

Comment: No, what I need is to disable the current redirection that WAMP has. I have the "mod_rewrite" plugin disabled and, even so, the server keeps redirecting the request as I mentioned in the main question...